# Segfault when using std::set of pointers... can anyone explain this?

Tags: c++, inheritance, pointers, segmentation-fault

In my game I created a base class called Entity which I store in a set for processing. All my game objects derive from this class, and I have no problem adding the derived pointer types to the set in my initialization function.

The problem lies in adding new elements from *within* an Entity's `Step()` function. Now, before I get too far into it I'll show you some simplified code:

```
class GameState
{
    public:
        GameState();
        ~GameState();
        ...
        set<Entity*> entities;
        void Add(Entity* e);
        void Remove(Entity* e);
    protected:
        set<Entity*> added, removed;
};

class Entity
{
    public:
        Entity();
        Entity(GameState* parent);
        virtual ~Entity();
        virtual void Step(const sf::Input& input);
        ...
        virtual void Destroy();
    protected:
        GameState* game;
};
```

The functions Add and Remove in GameState simply add the argument *e* to the `added` and `removed` sets respectively. In the main loop (elsewhere in GameState), I move the elements from `added` to `entities` before processing and after processing I remove elements from `removed` from `entities`. This ensures that `entities` is not modified during iteration.

The Add/Remove functions are very simple:

```
void GameState::Add(Entity* e)
{
    added.insert(e);
}

void GameState::Remove(Entity* e)
{
    removed.insert(e);
}
```

Every derived Entity is passed a pointer to GameState in it's constructor that it keeps as `game`. So theoretically from the Step function I should be able to Add and Remove entities with a simple call like `game->Remove(this);`, but instead I get a segfault. After a night of googling and coming up with nothing, I was able to work around (part of) the problem by implementing `Entity::Destroy()` like so:

```
void Entity::Destroy()
{
    game->Remove(this);
}
```

So my first question is: Why does `this` work when I'm in the base class but not in the derived class?

Even more puzzling to me is `Add()`. Why does `Add(new Explosion(16,16,this))` work in GameState but `game->Add(new Explosion(16,16,game))` doesn't work inside my object?

I ran it through gdb and it tells me:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
At c:/program files (x86)/codeblocks/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.1/include/c++/bits/stl_tree.h:482
```

The code that throws the error is:

```
_Link_type
  _M_begin()
  { return static_cast<_Link_type>(this->_M_impl._M_header._M_parent); } //this line
```

So to sum it up I have no idea why my pointers break the STL... and I get that grave feeling that I'm missing something very basic and its causing all these headaches. Can anyone give me advice?

Comment: So less code. No code when `std::set` is used.

Comment: How do you keep main Entity array, one that you are stepping over?

Comment: @Nawaz: I edited it to show how std::set gets used in the helper functions. Note that those are the last lines in the stack trace that I wrote. The pointers I pass to them _should be_ valid, as I only pass pointers to subclasses of Entity, but for some reason they aren't.

Comment: @elevener I am using std::set<Entity*> instead of an array

Comment: @aeron005 - in such case there and how do you delete your objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does `Add(new Explosion(16,16,this))` work in `GameState` but
>   `game->Add(new Explosion(16,16,game))` doesn't work inside my object?

If that is the case then the only possible explanation is that the `Entity`'s `game` member doesn't actually point to the `GameState`. Check that it is being set properly on construction and verify before you use it.

This has nothing to do with `std::set`. The problem is that you are using an `std::set` that is part of a class that you are accessing via a corrupt pointer.

Comment: This was it! So now I have a quick follow-up question. In my constructor for Entity, I go ahead and assign the value "game = parent;". In Explosion, I call the parent constructor like so:

"Explosion::Explosion(int xx, int yy, GameState* parent) : Entity(parent), frame(0)"

Doing it this way produced the error, but if I put "game = parent;" it works. Why do I have to assign it each time? Shouldn't it get assigned in the base class constructor when I call it?

Comment: Calling the parent constructor will only set `game` if the `Entity` constructor sets `game`. Are you setting `game` in `Entity::Entity(GameState* parent)`?